# Cuando guardo un formulario con nested_form_fields la consola de queda en BEGIN - Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Necesito su ayuda por favor.
No puedo crear un nuevo registro con otros registros anidados, porque la consola se queda en `BEGIN`, o sea, solo sale la primera consulta, que es la que crea el registro principal, pero no continua nunca para insertar los anidados. Cuando actualizo si funciona perfectamente.
Probé en MySQL cambiar `tx_isolation` de `REPEATABLE-READ` a `READ-UNCOMMITTED` pero nada ha pasado.
Adjunto las imagenes para que comprendan un poco mas el asunto.
Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El log que estás mostrando no es suficiente para saber cual puede ser el error, muestra código del create de tu controlador y los parámetros permitidos, también los modelos involucrados. Otra, no agregues pantallazos como con el log, mejor copia el texto que es mas fácil de manipular para quienes te puedan dar una respuesta tanto para el pantallazo como el código soliitado. Por último, el uml no corresponde a lo que tienes en tu bd. En el uml la tabla sale como `KitBase`, sin embargo el `INSERT` es ejecutado en `kitbases`, con que agregues el código de los modelos debería ser suficiente.

Comment: A propósito, lo del cambio de `tx_isolation` yo creo que no era necesario. Dudo mucho que el problema venga por el lado de mysql, lo mas probable es que esté en tu código.

Comment: Hola Alter, gracias por tus sugerencias el modelo relacional lo quería usar para ilustrar un ejemplo de la relación. Quisiera poder haber mostrado mas información pero no muestra nada mas, ahí se muere todo y la pagina queda cargando y la consola tal como la ves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

primero citar que tengo sistema operativo Debian Jessie, cambié a SQLite y me funcionó perfectamente. Luego vi la necesidad de buscar una solución ya que en mi empresa es necesario trabajar con MySQL y casualmente encontré una actualización al servidor. Instale tal actualización (Server version: 5.7.14 MySQL Community Server (GPL)) y luego de instalar la actualización volví a probar los formularios anidados y funcionan perfectamente bien, gracias a Dios.